# If $f(log_g(x))=x$ then what function is $f$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

If $f(log_g(x))=x$ then what function is $f$? I am looking for the inverse function to $log_g(x)$.

Comment: how is $\log_g$ defined? you can get an answer from that

Comment: $log_g(x)=k$ so $g^k=x$; $log_g(x)=log_g(x)$ substituting $log_g(x)$ for $k$ gives $g^{log_g(x)}=x$ so $f(x)=g^x$; is this what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f$ is an exponential function :

$$f(x)=g^x$$